# Atlanta Sitecore User Group - November 16, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**Date/Time (EST):** Thursday, November 16, 2017, 6:30 PM

**Date/Time (UTC):** Thursday, November 16, 2017, 23:30

**Location:** [Roam Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us), 3365 Piedmont Rd NE, Suite 1400, Atlanta, GA

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Sitecore/events/243388258

**Twitter:** [@AtlantaSitecore](https://twitter.com/atlantasitecore)

[image: Atlanta Sitecore User Group]

Like our November meeting last year, this event will be a post-Sitecore Symposium meetup where we will share exciting new updates, announcements and lessons from the 2017 Sitecore Symposium in Las Vegas.

As usual, dinner and drinks will be served.

### Presentations

#### Sitecore 9 Tools for Marketers and Other Shiny Objects

**Speakers**:

- [Rick Bauer](https://www.linkedin.com/in/bauerproductions/) ([@Sitecordial](https://twitter.com/sitecordial)) / Senior Technical Consultant at [Perficient](https://www.perficient.com/) & Sitecore Strategist MVP

Fresh off of Sitecore Symposium we will take a look at some of the new functionality in Sitecore 9, talk about the importance of organizational maturity, and explore a couple SBOS tools that can make everyone’s life easier right now in version 8.x.

#### No-Compromise Headless Solutions with Sitecore JavaScript Services

**Speakers**:

- [Nick Wesselman](https://www.linkedin.com/in/nickwesselman/) ([@techphoria414](https://twitter.com/techphoria414)) / Platform Architect at [Sitecore](https://www.sitecore.net/)
- [Brian Beckham](https://www.linkedin.com/in/brianbeckham/) ([@brianbeckham](https://twitter.com/brianbeckham)) / [BrainJocks](http://www.brainjocks.com/) CEO & Sitecore Technology MVP

Now available in Tech Preview! Learn how Sitecore JavaScript Services allows you to develop Sitecore solutions in 100% JavaScript, using modern JavaScript tools and frameworks, without compromising any Experience Platform functionality. Hear from Sitecore partner (and JSS beta testers) [BrainJocks](http://www.brainjocks.com/) about their experience and lessons learned from running a test project using JSS.

#### Leveraging Sitecore to Access All Your Data to Help Drive Your Brand’s Digital Destiny

**Speakers**:

- [Eric Stafford](https://www.linkedin.com/in/eric-stafford-a0615632/) ([@sitecoreeric](https://twitter.com/sitecoreeric)) / Lead Sitecore Technical Consultant at [Arke](http://www.arke.com/)
- [Neil Killen](https://www.linkedin.com/in/neil-killen-9a7a024/) ([@NeilKillen](https://twitter.com/NeilKillen)) / Sitecore Architect at [Arke](http://www.arke.com/)

[Eric Stafford](https://www.linkedin.com/in/eric-stafford-a0615632/) and [Neil Killen](https://www.linkedin.com/in/neil-killen-9a7a024/) attended the Symposium Integration Bootcamp and will provide a summary of what they learned about Sitecore's data integration capabilities that are now available through xConnect and the Data Exchange Framework.